# How to allow or block the notifications alert on headless chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, protractor

I am running my protractor tests on **headless** chrome for which I am not sure whether the headless chrome pops up the Notification alert or not.

[image]

If it pops up then how to Allow and Block them?

For non-headless chrome I have added the workaround given in this [post](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2626).

How to detect for headless and make it allow or block?

I am using Angular2 application and non angular2 application.