# How to execute the command in angular2 protractor test suite

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

My requirement is to allow the pop up when a certain button is clicked which generates it in the headless chrome browser.
I am using angular2 application and protractor for testing in typescript.
The following command is taken from the SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242264/chromedriver-headless-alerts).

**Problems faced:** When I type this command in my IDE it displays error as cannot find name driver.

```
driver.ExecuteJavaScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```

Comment: When I changed to `browser.ExecuteJavaScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");` it displays error after running the test as  `- Failed: protractor_1.browser.ExecuteJavaScript is not a function`

Comment: try this: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {JavascriptExecutor jsDriver = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;jsDriver.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");

Comment: It executed by browser.executeScript.... but it is not working as expected by not clicking on Allow button.

Comment: Add this driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Comment: @Subhashini please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225378/how-to-allow-or-block-the-notifications-alert-on-headless-chrome 
I have made it display the permission pop up as browser.executeScrit('Notification.permissionState()') which displays the pop up now how to click on allow and block button?